# How to add non-source folders to IntelliJ IDEA project

Tags: intellij-idea

Recently set up a multi module project in IntelliJ with the following structure:

```
/module1
/module2
/web-module
/sql
/lib
/a few more folders
```

I set up module1+2 and web-module as modules in IntelliJ so those show up, but how do you make the sql and lib folder show up in the project panel? They should be included in VCS as well, but IntelliJ ignores them. How do you add folders outside modules to a project?

Screenshot of project and explorer view:

[image]

Comment: Use **Add Content Root** button in the module `Sources` tab.

Comment: But this is project bound content, there is no fitting module for them

Comment: For those switching to eclipse, just create your Project from existing sources, then chose Import from eclipse. It will find everything. I was earlier just creating as non-eclipse. Hope this helps someone in the same boat as me. Eclipse is horrible in terms of retaining the right shortcut keys and it was annoying me. Back to loving IJ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Project view mode all directories (except the ignored ones from the settings) should show up. Of course the base folder for your multi-project has to be the folder above module1.

[image]

EDIT:

Your project should look like this (project view tree):

```
MY_PROJECT_ROOT (~/the/folder/to/your/project)
     |- /module1
     |- /module2
     |- /web-module
```

And in this case, you should definitely see the other folders. I got a sample project set up  where this is working.

EDIT 2:

From your screenshot, I assume you are missing the root directory (the project root is not as you expected). I added another screenshot. There should be a single root folder for your 3 modules. This one is missing at your screenshot. You have 3 separate folders with no common root folder. On MacOs, the project root is displayed in the window title. In my case it points to `~/devel/sandbox`.
I guess you should try to create a new project in for that `trunk` folder. From the scratch. Then add the existing modules and you should be fine?!

[image]

Comment: They do, however, not show up. A single file shows up outside the module folders, a properties file in the project root. So the project root should be set up correctly I think. Should I have some project file in my project root, or is .idea folder enough?

Comment: The `.idea` folder replaces the old project files (.ipr, .ipw). There should be .iml files in every module. That's it. Can you maybe add a screenshot from your IDE and your file system of that project root?

Comment: @mana, if I understand you correctly, if I want a project root with three modules in it, do I actually need FOUR modules (a "root" module with the same root as the project root and three modules underneath it)? I created a project, created three modules underneath the project root, and I couldn't see any other folders under the project root. Only when I created a root module with the same root as the project root could I see the additional folders.

Answer (score 65):

This is not a strict answer to the question, but it worked for me so I'm posting, perhaps someone will find this useful.

**If you want to add an arbitrary folder to your project** (even from some different location than your projects), just add it as a module. You needn't worry about the type so much e.g. I needed to add a folder with some SQL scripts, I added it as a Java module and it's nicely visible in IntelliJ even though it has no maven structure or Java sources.

This is how to do it:

- File > Project Structure > Modules
- Add > New Module > ... (e.g. Java Module)
- In the new module settings mark the subfolders that you want to see as 'Sources'

Voilà! :)

Comment: Very helpful indeed! Intellij is in this matter pretty confusing.

Comment: just what I was looking for, thks

Comment: Seems to work only if the module has java source files only.

Comment: @sdm at the time of writing of the above post, it definitely worked with non-java files (as mentioned in my case SQL). In fact I've just tried this approach with Intellij Community Edition 2017.3.4 and it still worked for me.

Comment: Yes I think the problem is a bit nuanced. If I want to add a random folder which has some java code, it'll select only the folder containing java source code as the source folder.

Comment: All I wanted was to include an external dir for reference and I did exactly what you did, except choose 'from existing sources', over and over again and it just would not work. Your post with the word 'arbitrary' gave me confidence I was doing things right, and suddenly it worked the nth time !! So guys, if this doesn't seem to work, try and try again :)

Comment: @killjoy ha, sometimes such a detail makes a difference... glad it helped you :)

Comment: I found @ondrej-burkert solution to be simpler and works for any kind of content in the added folder. It got my upvote also.

Answer (score 11):

This is something that I typically see when creating a project from existing modules.  All the modules will show in the project but not the other project related directories.  These directories might be, configuration files, environment scripts or bundles of SQL scripts that don't fit neatly into an Intellij module type.

To show the rest of the project source files and directories, I create a parent module from the project root.

File->Project Structure->Modules

1. Create a new module using the + sign.  The new module could be any type (I use java).
2. On the **Next** screen set the **Content root** and **Module file location** to the Project's root folder.
3. Select **Finish**

All of your other modules should now be submodules of the root, and your other project files should now show up.

Answer (score 8):

Add and remove content roots

To add a new content root:

1. Go to File | Project Structure, or press Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S.
2. Select Modules under the Project Settings section.
3. Select the necessary module, and then open the Sources tab in the right-hand part of the dialog.
4. Click Add Content Root.
5. Specify the folder that you want to add as a new content root, and click OK.

[image]

source: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html

Answer (score 5):

I used `File -> New -> Module from Existing Sources...`

[image]

Then I simply select the folder and add it.